# Initialization in pLSA

Tags: machine-learning, latent-semantic-analysis

I'm using pLSA (Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis). I'm trying to estimate the best value for some parameters with a process of k-fold cross-validation.

I have noticed that the model fitting is strongly influenced by the initialization. In order to choose the "best" initialization i'm using the trivial method of multiple random initializations.

Does someone know if do it exist a better way?Or maybe some good practices?